# Redirection based on the current Geolocation of the user

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

My website is kind of an area-wise shops listing site. When a user logs in to his account, the page should be redirected to his area's shop listing page based on the geolocation (HTML5)!

Is this possible? I have a very little knowledge of geolocation based on HTML5 standards. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

well you can get users location using the html5's geolocation api.
following is the syntax

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}
```

now in successCallBack, you can access users co ordinates using following syntax

```
position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude
```

you can also find a interesting [demo](http://html5demos.com/geo).